# jquery missing ) after argument list on radiobutton form

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I copied a pice of jquery code from a tutorial for working with radio buttons. It is not working for me but from the comments on the tutorial it seems to work for other people. I get this "missing ) after argument list" } else { 
So here is the relevant portion of my code. I have two radio buttons above two forms. I want to show the form with the checked radio button and hide the other form.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#existing-login').show();
          $('#new-customer').hide();
        });

        $("input[@name='customer']").change(function(){
            if ($("input[@name='customer']:checked").val() == "new")
                $("#new-customer").show();
                $("#existing-login").hide();
            } else {
                $("#existing-login").show();
                $("#new-customer").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>

   <input type="radio" name="customer" value="existing" checked="checked"/>
   <input type="radio" name="customer" value="new"/>

        <div id="existing-login">
            <!-- form for existing customer login -->
        </div>
        <div id="new-customer">
            <!-- form for new customers -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Missing `{` after your if statement:

```
if ($("input[@name='customer']:checked").val() == "new") {
    $("#new-customer").show();
    $("#existing-login").hide();
} else {
    $("#existing-login").show();
    $("#new-customer").hide();
}
```

Also the `@` syntax for selecting attributes isn't supported anymore in current versions of jQuery, so remove that too:

```
if ($("input[name='customer']:checked").val() == "new") {
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that! No wonder it wasn't working. Thank you. Oxygen is a great editor for xslt but it doesn't highlight javascript.

Comment: I take it back, the above suggestions still do no make this work. I'm no longer getting the error but now nothing happens at all. `$("input[name='customer']").change(function(){
         alert('Changed'); // This alert never activates
        }`

Comment: I'll consider this answered because you did fix the error with "missing ) after argument list". But it is a new problem that the above code still doesn't work. This line $("input[name='customer']").change(function(){ alert('Changed'); } never activates but I found a workaround by writing a function to show and hide the forms and activated the function with onclick. In the end it all worked out and I thank you for your help @boltClock.

Comment: Sorry for not following up sooner. Great that you found a solution :)